# JsPlumb IE 8 error: 'jsPlumb.Endpoints[...]' is null or not an object

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jsplumb

I am using JS plumb 1.5.5, the basic case is working fine on chrome, IE 10 and mozilla. But i am getting the ERROR : **'jsPlumb.Endpoints[...]' is null or not an object** , when running the same on IE version 8.0.7600.16385. I tried debugging the javascript and found that the error is happening because **_jsPlumb.getRenderMode() is undefined**. I tried setting the renderMode to VML and SVG but still i get the same error. I have to support this on IE8 as well. The sample code thats throwing the error is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
        <!-- library scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.5.5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contextMenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wfeditor.js"></script>
        <style>
            .item {
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: #ddddff;
                width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #state1 {
            left: 100px;
            top: 100px;
        }

        #state2 {
            left: 250px;
            top: 100px;
        }

        #state3 {
            left: 100px;
            top: 250px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="state1" class="item"></div>
        <div id="state2" class="item"></div>
        <div id="state3" class="item"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jsPlumb.ready(function() {
            jsPlumb.makeSource($('.item'), {
                connector: 'StateMachine'
            });
            jsPlumb.makeTarget($('.item'), {
            anchor: 'Continuous'
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: would be good if you can create a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue